# signalr failed to connect to LongPolling or serverSentEvents transport when using sqlserver scaleout

Tags: signalr, signalr-backplane

When i am using sqlserver scaleout with signalr `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer`, it failed to connect to `LongPolling` or `serverSentEvents` transport.

Anyone faced this error before, i am using `signalr 2.2.1` and `signalr.sqlserver 2.2.1`.

here is my full code in owin startup class

```
 GlobalHost.Configuration.TransportConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30); 
    string sqlConnectionString = "Server=NCBCDEV;Database=SignalR2;Integrated 
    Security=true"; SqlScaleoutConfiguration sqlcon = new 
    SqlScaleoutConfiguration(sqlConnectionString); 
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(sqlcon ); app.MapSignalR(); 
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(Microsoft.AspN‌​et.SignalR.Hubs.IAss‌​emblyLocator), () => new AssemblyLocator());
```

EventSource connected:

```
13:59:38.277 :82/signalr/hubs/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&conn…48Kldg%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&tid=0:1 GET http://ncbcdev:82/signalr/hubs/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientPro…zC48Kldg%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&tid=0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
13:59:38.278 
SignalR: serverSentEvents transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
longPolling transport starting.
SignalR: longPolling transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
13:59:52.655 jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9 [13:59:52 GMT+0300 (Arab Standard Time)] SignalR: Fallback transports exhausted.
```

Comment: Please share the backplane configuration code.

Comment: here is my full code in owin startup class

 GlobalHost.Configuration.TransportConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
string sqlConnectionString = "Server=NCBCDEV;Database=SignalR2;Integrated Security=true"; 
SqlScaleoutConfiguration sqlcon = new SqlScaleoutConfiguration(sqlConnectionString);
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(sqlcon );         
app.MapSignalR();
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.IAssemblyLocator), () => new AssemblyLocator());

Comment: @dev could this error be because of permission on the DB, although the tables are created automatically!